# How to make this slider slides with Alpine js?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have a slider which uses Alpine js but struggle to get the slides to slide automatically with Alpine js.
At the moment, the slider only slides on manual inputs.

Any idea how to get a slide to slide for example, every 2 seconds?

Thanks!

```
        <div x-data="carousel()" class="relative">
            <img
                class="h-[500px] w-full object-cover object-center"
                :src="images[selected]"
                alt="mountains"
            />

            <button
                @click="if (selected > 0 ) {selected -= 1} else { selected = images.length - 1 }"
                class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 px-2 py-[25%] h-full w-8 group hover:bg-gray-500 hover:bg-opacity-75 cursor-pointer"
            >
        <span class="hidden group-hover:block text-gray-50">
          &larr;
        </span>
            </button>
            <button
                @click="if (selected < images.length - 1  ) {selected += 1} else { selected = 0 }"
                class="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 px-2 py-[25%] h-full w-8 group hover:bg-gray-500 hover:bg-opacity-75 cursor-pointer"
            >
        <span class="hidden group-hover:block text-gray-50">
          &rarr;
        </span>
            </button>

            <div class="absolute bottom-0 w-full p-4 flex justify-center space-x-2">
                <template x-for="(image,index) in images" :key="index">
                    <button
                        @click="selected = index"
                        :class="{'bg-gray-300': selected == index, 'bg-gray-500': selected != index}"
                        class="h-2 w-2 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-300 ring-2 ring-gray-300"
                    ></button>
                </template>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            const carousel = () => {
                return {
                    selected: 0,
                    images: [
                        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506905925346-21bda4d32df4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2070&q=80",
                        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464822759023-fed622ff2c3b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2070&q=80",
                        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500534314209-a25ddb2bd429?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=987&q=80",
                        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486870591958-9b9d0d1dda99?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2070&q=80",
                        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1485160497022-3e09382fb310?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2070&q=80",
                        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472791108553-c9405341e398?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2137&q=80"
                    ]
                };
            };
        </script>
```